# Rake Not Finding Dependencies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

Why would the file not be loaded? Any help is much appreciated.

rake db:setup RAILS_ENV="development" --trace

```
   rake aborted!
   no such file to load -- rqrcode
```

/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/barby-0.4.4/lib/barby/barcode/qr_code.rb:1:in `require'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you require 'rqrcode'. Maybe it's a missing gem that you need to install?

Comment: Wouldn't running bundle install find the dependencies of the barby gem?

Comment: I'm thinking it may be an issue with the bundler?

Comment: I can give you more output. I've been struggling with this for a while

Comment: I don't think so, doesn't the bundler require the dependencies to be listed?